# active tab in css

Tags: jquery, html, css, click

I am having lengthy structure of bootstrap theme classes.

**This is menu i am designing.**

[image: Dashboard select with current '.active' class-]

Have this code for this menu bar design in bootstrap-

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><span
                        class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a><a class="brand" href="#">My Menu</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a  href="/Home/Dashboard"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li ><a href="#" id="taskMainLink">Task</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#" id="contactMainLink">Contact</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#" id="appointmentMainLink">Appointment</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#" id="projectMainLink">Project</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#" id="salesMainLink">Sales</a></li>

                        </ul>
```

**Now Issue**

I want each tab to be active on mouseclick and other tabs should be in original state.
Current active class is dashboard by default i did.

**Structure i am following for each time i click on any tab-**

```
$('.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-inverse>.container-fluid>.nav-collapse>.nav').click(function(){
$(this).find('li').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Am i going right class into class? Please suggest me right solution if i am wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul.nav li a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().children('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this.parentNode).addClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: can you please give comments on parentNode, How it finds parent element?

Comment: The `this.parentNode` is the selector, which selects the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```
$('ul.nav li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be easier for you to use the bootstrap [buttonDropdown](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns) component that does this for you.

Try to use these button dropdowns with the [buttonGroups](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups) component to make your buttons group together and apply your css to make it look like your menu at the moment.

You won't need any additional JavaScript to make your menu work!